# Node js Convert from utf-8

Tags: node.js, decode, encode, fs, utf

I have a product names in mysql but the some names are with Ö Ə Ü etc. I have to convert this chars to O E U and write to the jpeg file name. I try to  use utf8 package but it convert to Ã¼zlÃ¼k for example. How can I do this?

Comment: So, why can you not just store and utilized utf8 naming everywhere? And why are names of jpegs on the disc directly correlate with the values of fields that are meant to be used somewhere outside?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there is another option than replacing all those characters using a table containing all characters together with their replacement.

Luckily there is already a library solving this problem:
https://github.com/dundalek/latinize

Comment: If you are using the files only server side or in your own markup, the answer Robert provided seems the better solution. My answer applies if users download the result or see the filename for some other reason like as an email attachment.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that this would be a one-way operation, a Ö is *not* the same as an O. Instead of using the product names themselves, I would rather create a MD5 hash from them and use the hashes as filenames.